# Xcode 6 is showing funny characters

Tags: xcode, swift

I am having problem with Xcode 6, which starts showing funny and annoying characters as seen below.  I think I typed certain key that mistakenly made my Xcode editor show such annoying stuff.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get my editor into normal state?

[image: Weird characters]

Comment: It looks like you've enabled displaying non-printing characters. Look around the Editor menu and similar to see if there's an option to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

You've accidentally enabled the "Show Invisibles" option, located in the Editor menu:

[image: Show Invisibles]

Simply click that option (now "Hide Invisibles") again to hide the characters.

Comment: This does not exist in my version of xCode. Thanks, Apple.

Comment: Vielen Dank 
I was wondering how to articulate this question :D